# Does a vertex always have a path to iteself even if it doesn't have an edge to itself?

Tags: java, algorithm, testing, graph-theory

So I have created a method called hasPath that checks if there is a path between two given vertices. It passes all the test methods except one test method that asserts that a graph with vertecies without edges hasPath is False.

When I create a new graph in the main method and do this to an empty graph

> System.out.println(Graph.hasPath(g, 0, 0));

It returns true, meaning it assumes that a vertex has an edge to itself.

So I changed this line on line 8:

> if (topVertex == w)

to

> if(g.hasEdge(topVertex, w))

Now it returns false which is good, but my question is this why it was failing the test method I mentioned (I don't have access to the test method). Also what difference does this change make? I feel like "==" still does the job?

This is my first implementation.

````java
    public static boolean hasPath(Graph g, int v, int w) {
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean [] visited = new boolean[g.numVertices()];
        queue.offer(v);
        visited[v] = true;
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            int topVertex = queue.poll();
            if(topVertex == w){
                return true;
            }            
            Iterator<Integer> it = g.neighbors(topVertex);

            while(it.hasNext()){
                int ite = it.next();
                if(!visited[ite]){
                    visited[ite]=true;
                    queue.offer(ite);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    
    }
        ```
````

Comment: It depends on your situation and requirements. A conventional way of seeing it is that a path consists of *0 or more* edges and that a path of length 0 ends in the same vertex where it starts. Seeing it this way the vertex has no edge to itself but still has a path to itself. A path consisting of 0 edges.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're telling me that a vertex has always a path to itself even if it doesn't have an edge to itself? It kinda makes sense, but then I am back to square one. I've implemented different version of the test method myself and my first implementation of hasPath passes all of them except for when I ask it if a vertex has a path to itself?

Comment: Disallowing the empty path is in poor taste IMO. Let P be the binary relation where vPw means "there is a simple path from v to w" (assuming an undirected graph, but this also applies with modifications to directed). With empty paths, P is an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, transitive), which is a really nice property. Without empty paths, P in general is only symmetric (!). We expect to lose reflexivity (vPv), but if vPw, then wPv, and since we don't have vPv, we've lost transitivity too. Obviously, however, if this is an assignment, whoever wrote the test case has the last word.

Comment: I didn't tell you to look at it that way in your context. But you understood correctly, what you say is what I consider a conventional and nice way to look at it for many purposes.

Comment: I agree but if you look at the name of the test method it says "graphWithVerteciesWithoutEdgesHasPathIsFalse". Doesn't it mean that if there is no edges then there is no path?

Comment: @User Yes, the person who wrote that test considers no edges to imply no path. But I would disagree. This is ultimately an argument about definitions with no "right" answer (but a prettier answer and an uglier answer, IMO).

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is common to look at it like Ole V.V. describes it in the first comment. I've never seen any teaching material that would suggest otherwise. Also intuition, if I am at home, there is a path to my home, even if I don't have the keys and doors lock automatically, so I cannot come back when leaving, but if I am right there now then I have a path.

Comment: @maraca I couldn't agree more! But the problem is then I have literally no idea what is wrong with my code. I have spent a bit over 2 days trying to figure this out now and I've not found anything. Would you please look at the code if you can spot maybe something that might affect the test method?

Comment: @David Eisenstat so you're telling me that No Edge, No Path is also about a vertex's relation to itself? But in anycase should I keep the "if == " statement or change it by "if has edge statement"?

Comment: Also I should add that it is a weighted graph

Comment: This isn't really a graph theory problem. You can either follow the spec as is, not follow the spec as is, or get the spec changed. The consensus in this comment thread is that the spec *should* be changed, but we can't change it for you. (Your `hasPath` is basically what I would have written.)

Comment: @User as said by David Eisenstat your solution is fine, but they want to see something different, so you have to go with it. But you could say that you didn't understand at first and it would be helpful to include whether path to same node always exists or not. My guess is they made a mistake in the checker, but I would avoid saying they did something wrong or they feel threatened and can get annoying to deal with.